# What does Google mean by alwaysOnTop?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to develop a Chrome App that is always on top of all other windows, including Chrome and other applications. I haven't had any success when using `alwaysOnTop = true`.

What does [google](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-CreateWindowOptions) mean when it says:

> If true, the window will stay above **most other windows**. If there are multiple windows of this kind, the currently focused window will be in the foreground.

What are these "most other windows"? How do I know which windows it means? So far it hasn't stayed on top of any other windows once I click away from the app. I have placed my script below in case it's something simple that I have missed.

```
function openApp() {
var innerBounds = {
    left : 0,
    top : 0.8 * screen.height,
    width : screen.width,
    height : 0.2 * screen.height,
};
var frame = {
    type : "none",
};
var options = {
    id : "lqps",
    innerBounds : innerBounds,
    frame : frame,
    resizable : false,
    alwaysOnTop : true,
    visibleOnAllWorkspaces : true,
    };
    chrome.app.window.create("popup.html", options);
}
```

I hope someone has worked all of this out.

Comment: Did you add the permission?

Comment: @DanielHerr, I have the permission: `"alwaysOnTopWindows"`. It didn't _seem_ to work. But this is mostly what my question is about: what does alwaysOnTop even mean relative to Chrome Apps?

Comment: You can try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hcbhfbnaaancmblfhdknlnojpafjohbi

Comment: @DanielHerr thanks for this. I will trawl through the source and (hopefully) uncover the secret to getting `alwaysOnTop` to work.

Comment: So I added the line: `console.log(chrome.app.window.get("lqps").isAlwaysOnTop());` and this returned `true`. I have gotten no closer to why the _Window State_ app example you linked above works and my code above does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your manifest.json try this:

```
"permissions": [
  "identity",
  "app.window.alwaysOnTop"
  ],
```

And in your background.js try:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    id: 'mainWindow',
    innerBounds: { 
      width: 260, 
      height: 190, 
      minWidth: 254,
      maxWidth: 508,
      minHeight: 190,
      maxHeight: 190
    },
    frame:{
      type: "chrome"
    },
    state: "normal",
    hidden: false,
    resizable: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true
  });
});
```

or just this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    id: 'mainWindow',
    alwaysOnTop: true
  });
});
```

**EDIT**
Ok as i am after a similar thing i done the following to achieve a second popup options menu:
1. Add the above script to the manifest.json
2. Format your background.js similar to mine below:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    id: 'mainWindow',
    innerBounds: { 
      width: 260, 
      height: 190
    },
    frame:{
      type: "chrome"
    },
    state: "normal",
    hidden: false,
    resizable: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true
  },        
  );
});

document.querySelector("#OptionsWin").addEventListener("click", optionWindow);
function optionWindow(){
  chrome.app.window.create('options.html', {
    id: 'optionsWindow',
    innerBounds: { 
      width: 260, 
      height: 190
    },
    frame:{
      type: "chrome"
    },
    state: "normal",
    hidden: false,
    resizable: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true
  }
  );
}
```

3. Now in you HTML file make sure you add:

`<script src="background.js"></script>`

This also works if you put the listener and the function in another .js file as long as you include its location in the .html file.

4. Some code editors might provide issue's when testing the code, its best to use the browser extension launch for testing or i have found "Chrome Dev Editor" and good coding platform to launch the app from (not so much for publishing to the web though, had to do that manually). so if there is problems with windows not obeying intended function try Chrome Dev Editor.

Comment: This only worked once I changed `id` to `'mainWindow'`. Is this a thing? Does the `id` always have to be `'mainWindow'`? Thanks for your help! But now the sizes I dictated in `innerBounds` seem to be ignored =(

Comment: Tbh i haven't tried it with other window id's. Technically it shouldn't make a difference what the id is. For the innerBounds make sure you have the settings for resizable set to false. I am still figuring a few things out also. Will try the other window id out later as i need a second window for settings on my app.

Comment: This is a journey for us both. So now I have discovered that it virtually ignores `width` and `height` if you don't also set the min and (or?) max values. So far, for me at least, it only worked with `id: 'mainWindow'` and right now it still ignores `top` and `left` values that I have set.

Comment: I overcame this by using `chrome.app.window.get('mainWindow').innerBounds.setPosition(x,y);` after I had initialised the window. Hopefully, I'll work out why later on. Let us know if you also find that the name needs to be `mainWindow` and we can set your answer as the answer.

Comment: Are you calling the window in the background.js? Or a forward js file like a main.js.

Comment: Calling the window in background.js then setting the location properties in a forward js.

Comment: ok i renamed my window and it  still displays on top. i am wondering if its cause you are not (or from what i can tell) running the `chrome.app.window.create('popup.html', {` in the  `chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {` and running it at the start. i would try the format i have done above.

Comment: or is it that this is an additional window and you are calling it from your other windows UI? in this case you will need to use a listener to look out for the UI call and i am not 100% sure you can do that in a background.js but will have a go now.

Comment: i edited my answer, hope it works for you as it does for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110099/discussion-between-mowglib-and-david).